# Insert Multiple lines using suitescript 2.0 in Bin number in NetSuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I'm trying to insert multiple lines at a time by using record.insertLine() in SuiteScript 2.0 is that possible to do.

Comment: What script type are you using? Also can you share the code snippet.

Comment: in both scenarios 2.0 and 1.0.

Comment: If you call record.insertLine() in a loop, it should be possible.